# 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable when trying to SUM two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to find the sum of all elements inside bike_2011 and bike_2012.

The function referenced looks like this was supplied by our tutors:

```py
def count_days(year, month, day):
    year_2011=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    year_2012=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

    if (year == 2011):
        days= sum(year_2011[:(month-1)])+day
    else:
        days= 365+sum(year_2012[:month-1])+day
    return days
```

So far I have tried:

```py
bike_2011 = bike[count_days(2011, 0, 0)-1]
bike_2012 = bike[count_days(2012, 0, 0)-1]
print(sum(bike_2011 + bike_2012))
```

It then returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-0a8e1898fa46> in <module>
----> 1 print(sum(bike_2011 + bike_2012))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please provide us with your array `bike`

Comment: look at this example: `sum(2+3)` vs `sum([2,3])`. You should use `sum([bike_2011,bike_2012])` since sum expects an iterable object and a list is iterable.

Comment: The array is a text file with several hundred elements. There is one column and each row represents a date. I.e the first row is 801.0 so 801 bikes were sold on the 1st of January 2011 the last element represents 31st of December. https://pastebin.com/ubV6hyqt

Comment: sum([bike_2011,bike_2012]) does that return the amount of elements or the sum of the value of each element? I would have expected the number returned to be much higher than 9281.0

Comment: it returns the sum of all values. Take care that `bike_2011` and `bike_2012` are floats not arrays

Comment: Ah okay, how would I go about converting them to integers

Comment: `int(bike_2011)`

Comment: Beuno. Cheers mate!